# Can I allow negative numbers in PHP getopt()? without "--" flag, that is

Tags: php, command-line, getopt

I have a command line script that accepts an integer value. (It is not meant as a flag in getopt).

I also use getopt() to accept some command line flags.

Sometimes my integers need to be negative.  However, negative numbers trigger getopt to parse them (unless preceded by -- to stop command line flag processing, which is kind of ugly, but might be my only option).

**Is there a graceful way to allow negative numbers in the command line without the '--', and by only using standard libraries/functions?**

examples:

```
php box.php -r 5 some text arguments here

php box.php -r -5 some other text here  # fails, as -5 is treated as a flag

php box.php -r -- -5 some other text here  # workaround
```

(note: 5 and -5 are not values for the -r flag.  -r is a boolean flag)

Comment: Did you tried with `php box.php -r '-5' some other text here`

Comment: Try `php box.php -r=-5 some text arguments here`

Comment: -5 is not a value meant for the -r flag.  -r is a boolean flag

Comment: "-5" does not help, as the shell removes the quotes and treats it as the tokens -5, the same as without quotes